# JavaScript not checking logical statements

Tags: javascript, php, forms

Im having a problem with javascript not checking my code correctly. I hope someone can tell me what specifically is going wrong in this case. What I'm trying to achieve is that if any of the fields are blank, or password field is less than 8 characters, an alert should show with either of the possible outcomes. However, if I enter anything else than all fields blank, it just submits the form and sends me to the next page.
Am I missing something fundamental here?

```
<script>
function validateForm()
{
//var x=document.register.username.value
var x="document.forms["register"]["username"].value";
var y="document.forms["register"]["homeaddress"].value";
var z="document.forms["register"]["password"].value";
if (x == "" || y == "" || z == "")       {
alert("You must fill in all fields in the application");

return false;
} else if (z.length < 8) {
alert("Passwords must be at least 8 characters long");
 return false;
   }

return true;
}
</script>
```

The form is as follows:

```
<form name="register" method="post" action="tryregister.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();">

Username: <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="50"><br>
Home address: <input type="text" name="homeaddress" maxlength="50"><BR>
Password: <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="50"><br>

<input type="submit" value="Register me!">
```

Comment: The syntax highlighting here should give you a good indication of the issue. You shouldn't be quoting your `x`, `y`, or `z` values.

Comment: @WaleedKhan Thank you! This seemed to do the trick!

Comment: JavaScript works correctly. It's your code that's broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly access form elements. You have put them up inside a string:

Change below lines

```
var x="document.forms["register"]["username"].value";
var y="document.forms["register"]["homeaddress"].value";
var z="document.forms["register"]["password"].value";
```

to

```
var x=document.forms["register"].username.value;
var y=document.forms["register"].homeaddress.value;
var z=document.forms["register"].password.value;
```

Comment: Thank you! What are the security implications of using javascript to check input fields? Assume regex and mysqli input sanitation is done on the next page (Albeit no length checking).

Comment: To increase security, always do validations on the server side too.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the double quotes around

```
var x="document.forms["register"]["username"].value";
      ^^                                           ^^
```

Such that

```
var x = document.forms['register']['username'].value
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are missing the fundamental thing over here.

In your code,

```
var x="document.forms["register"]["username"].value";
var y="document.forms["register"]["homeaddress"].value";
var z="document.forms["register"]["password"].value";
```

You are declaring `x` to be a string `'document.forms["register"]["username"].value'`.

It should be an expression which should evaluate to some value.

So, please update this code to:

```
var x=document.forms["register"]["username"].value;
var y=document.forms["register"]["homeaddress"].value;
var z=document.forms["register"]["password"].value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the quotation marks around your assignments for `x`, `y`, and `z`:

```
var x=document.forms["register"]["username"].value;
var y=document.forms["register"]["homeaddress"].value;
var z=document.forms["register"]["password"].value";
```